# Qt QTreeView not updating when adding to model

Tags: c++, qt

The source code relating to this question is available on my [public Git repository on BitBucket](https://bitbucket.org/josefvanniekerk/hid-descriptor-builder/src).

I'm trying to dynamically add some items to a `QTreeView` model using the following code in [mainwindow.cpp](https://bitbucket.org/josefvanniekerk/hid-descriptor-builder/src/c3985948ed098378246265434674c8c24718f2b5/mainwindow.cpp?at=master#cl-70):

```
if(dlg->exec() == QDialog::Accepted) {
    QList<QVariant> qList;
    qList << item.name << "1111 0000" << "0x00";
    HidDescriptorTreeItem *item1 = new HidDescriptorTreeItem(qList, hidDescriptorTreeModel->root());
    hidDescriptorTreeModel->root()->appendChild(item1);
}
```

This works when run from within my `MainWindow` constructor, just after [`ui->setupUi(this)`](https://bitbucket.org/josefvanniekerk/hid-descriptor-builder/src/c3985948ed098378246265434674c8c24718f2b5/mainwindow.cpp?at=master#cl-5), but I need this to run from within an event filter, but the same code doesn't get the `QTreeView` updating. When I set a breakpoint at `mainwindow.cpp:70` and step through the next few lines, I can see the data is being added to the Model, but I need the `QTreeView` to refresh.

I understand this is done by emitting `dataChanged()`, but not really sure how to do this. The signal signature for the `dataChanged` signal looks as follows:

```
void dataChanged(const QModelIndex &topLeft, const QModelIndex &bottomRight, const QVector<int> &roles = QVector<int>());
```

so I need to come up with `topLeft` and `bottomRight` `QModelIndex` instances. How do I build/obtain these from `item1` in the above snippet?

Also, where does `beginInsertRows()` and `endInsertRows()` come into view with this, should I be calling these functions?

Comment: It is done by `rows[AboutToBe]Inserted` functions. So, what is `HidDescriptorTreeModel`?

Comment: HidDescriptorTreeModel is a class that inherits from QAbstractItemModel? ?

Comment: Hi guys, the HidDescriptorTreeModel extends QAbstractItemModel, I'll supply some more details by amending my question.

Comment: Question has been updated, with links to the BitBucket Git repository.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From QAbstractItemModel documentation:

```
void QAbstractItemModel::beginInsertRows ( const QModelIndex & parent, int first, int last ) [protected]
Begins a row insertion operation.
When reimplementing insertRows() in a subclass, you must call this function before inserting data into the model's underlying data store.
The parent index corresponds to the parent into which the new rows are inserted; first and last are the row numbers that the new rows will have after they have been inserted.
```

The other protected functions say similar things.

And insertRows() says:

> If you implement your own model, you can reimplement this function if
>   you want to support insertions. Alternatively, you can provide your
>   own API for altering the data. **In either case**, you will need to call
>   beginInsertRows() and endInsertRows() to notify other components that
>   the model has changed.

Take a look to QAbstractItemModel [protected functions](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qabstractitemmodel.html#protected-functions) and [signals](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qabstractitemmodel.html#signals)

Views connect to those signals to know when model data changes and rearrange data inside. The functions emit the signals internally to make it easy for you to warn the view when it has happenned. But signals can only be emitted by abstract class.

> Components connected to this signal use it to adapt to changes in the
>   model's dimensions. It can only be emitted by the QAbstractItemModel
>   implementation, and cannot be explicitly emitted in subclass code.

So you will have to stick to the methods.

**Edit in answer to your comment:**

Indeed, Items should have a reference to model and tell it about changes, check theses lines from QStandardItem:

[void QStandardItem::emitDataChanged()](http://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qt/blobs/85f42777111060037476895ed08ded513d44a048/src/gui/itemviews/qstandarditemmodel.cpp#line863)

[void QStandardItem::removeRows(int row, int count)](http://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qt/blobs/85f42777111060037476895ed08ded513d44a048/src/gui/itemviews/qstandarditemmodel.cpp#line1612)

( Note, how, in second, it calls model's rowsAboutToBeRemoved() and rowsRemoved() )

Maybe you should try to use [QStandardItem](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtgui/qstandarditem.html) and [QStandardItemModel](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtgui/qstandarditemmodel.html). 
Either direct or subclassing. It will hide a lot of ugly stuff.

Comment: I appreciate the comment. My problem is understanding where to call begin/endInsertRows(). It's easy to say that it needs to get called in the QAbstractItemModel, but being a tree structure, data often gets added via the appendChild() function which is part of HidDescriptorTreeItem, so that would need to refer to the parent Tree model somehow...I'm confusing myself. :)

Comment: Most useful thanks. I've also discovered the Editable Tree Model example that comes with QT Creator. That along with your answer makes thing quite a bit clearer!

Answer (score 1):

There's also a less proper but much easier way to achieve this - `emit layoutChanged()` instead of `dataChanged()`. More info - https://stackoverflow.com/a/41536459/635693

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted, this solved 2 days of bug hunting for me!